# Is it possible to install GeoServer on a web server?

Tags: geoserver, web-service, installation

Is it possible to install and use GeoServer with PostgreSQL on a website which is hosted by a web server provider?

I am using a web server for my website. I want to add mapping feature on my website. I know PostgreSQL for storing my data like shp files (postgres db is provided by the webhoster) but I do not know how can I install GeoServer and use to fetch data from postgreSQL and display on my website using Openlayers / Leaflet.

Comment: http://www.acugis.com/geoserver-hosting.htm does this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general - no. Webserver's are only dedicated to run webserver services on a certain port, e.g. offering HTML-content or processing simple PHP- or JS-Scripts.

GeoServer is software which wants to be [installed](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/linux/debian.html#installation) and maintained. It's like an own service in a server environment...

Of course, you could always ask your hoster via support if setting up services like GeoServer is possible. But they most likely will charge money for setting up custom software and you wont be able to customize the software anyways, only use it.

What you are looking for might be a [Virtual Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) or even a [dedicated Root Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedicated_hosting_service) with shell and/or remote desktop access and the ability to install Java, GeoServer and any software packages you want.

Answer (score 4):

I will say that it will not be possible.  Shared hosting has lots of limitations and here is the list of apps that are supported:  http://www.justhost.com/cgi/info/web_hosting

So we know they have postgres will you need postgis?  I doubt that is configured.  Plus withe intensity of most GIS needs you will be placiing a large load on the resources which they will not like.  The only real way to know if you can be supported is to call or email them directly and asked.  In general, if it is not listed then it is not supported.  However, if you just want to add basic mapping you could convert your data to geojson or kml and host those files and consume those directly without needing geoserver.

Answer (score 1):

I use [WebFaction](http://www.webfaction.com/) which has PostGreSQL/PostGIS and all of the supported libraries. I just let them know which database to enable PostGIS on and it was done in less than a day. I also installed GeoServer with lots of help from my IT nephew as an application listening on a port. It crashed often until I upgraded memory and now it runs fine.

Warning: Installing GeoServer is not for the faint of heart. I have very little experience with server side issues like that and I'd like to keep it that way.

p.s. Django is also available as an app and I have a couple of GeoDjango apps running also. So far no problem.

Hopes this helps